# create names of dataframes in a loop

Tags: python, dataframe

I need to give names to previously defined dataframes.

I have a list of dataframes :

```
liste_verif = ( dffreesurfer,total,qcschizo)
```

And I would like to give them a name by doing something like:

```
for h in liste_verif: 
    h.name = str(h)
```

Would that be possible ?

When I'm testing this code, it's doesn't work : instead of considering h as a dataframe, python consider each column of my dataframe. 
I would like the name of my dataframe to be 'dffreesurfer', 'total' etc...

Comment: You should consider just storing your dfs in a dict if you want to map a string name to a df

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `dict comprehension` and map DataFrames by values in list `L`:

```
dffreesurfer = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [7,8]})
total = pd.DataFrame({'col2': [1,5]})
qcschizo = pd.DataFrame({'col2': [8,9]})

liste_verif = (dffreesurfer,total,qcschizo)
L = ['dffreesurfer','total','qcschizo']

dfs = {L[i]:x for i,x in enumerate(liste_verif)}
print (dfs['dffreesurfer'])
   col1
0     7
1     8

print (dfs['total'])
   col2
0     1
1     5
```