# How can I create the name of a dataframe in a loop

Tags: python, pandas

I want to name my dataframes in a loop.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40235998/create-names-of-dataframes-in-a-loop) doesn't solve my problem in my understanding because I want to change my dataframes'n names not my columns's names.

So, I'd like to do something like this :

```py
dfx = [df123, df456]
names = [678, 01011]

for i, df in enumerate(dfx): 
    "df" + str(names[i]) = df.drop.loc[:,"column"]
```

It seems basic but I don't know what to look for.
There must be something to do with regex but I don't know where to look or to start.

Comment: You cannot use `"df" + str(names[i])` as a left-hand side in an assigment

Comment: Look at eval(). You're probably better off using an array of DataFrames and indexing into it, but if you can overcome scope issues then eval() is what you need.

Comment: Use a  dictionary of dataframes instead.

Comment: Don't try to do this, it is very bad practice. Use a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure for what purpose this could be needed, but I think you can instead of having many data frames with different names, you can add your data frames in a list, that list could have your different data frames, or maybe a Dict can help you to name each of your element(data frame).